# QFT and measures on distributions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions

Recently I came across the following slogan: ,,constructing quantum field theory on a space $X$ means constructing a measure on the space of all (Schwarz?) distributions $\mathcal{S}'(X)$''. I would like to understand this slogan in some more detail: here is my attempt. Constructing quantum field theory means constructing the Fock space $\mathcal{F}(H)$ where $H$ is a single particle state space. This Fock space is naturally isomorphic with the space $L^2$ on the space of distributions-the underlying isomorphism is called *Segal isomorphism*. This functional realization is more convienient to work with thus the main task is to construct a measure on the space of distributions. 
However as I have understood, the above argument is valid provided we restrict ourselves to *Gaussian* measures-so this approach does not cover situations where there is some interaction present.
I would be grateful if anybody could shed some light on those issues.

Comment: See: [A Perspective on Constructive Quantum Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3991), p.9 . Interacting theories have been constructed in 1+1 dimensional spacetime.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this amazing article!

Answer (score 4):

The term "slogan" may not be the best choice of words here. This is not about a commercial for toothpaste. Also, taking as a starting point "constructing a QFT means constructing a Fock space", while to some extent true in the free case, is not correct in general. If you are familiar with the Wightman axioms defining a QFT and want to understand what they have to do with probability measures on a space of distributions $\mathcal{S}'$, then you can look at Section 6.1 of the book by Glimm and Jaffe ["Quantum Physics, A Functional Integral Point of View"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387964775), 2nd Edition, for a precise set of axioms (going back to J. Fröhlich) on such measures for them to correspond to QFTs. Another useful reference on the matter, is the article ["Time-ordered products and Schwinger functions"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103904675), in CMP 1978, by Eckmann and Epstein.